# quick selection tool algorithm

Tags: image, image-processing, adobe, gimp

I was using adobe photoshop and I was amazed by the "[quick selection tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/photoshop/using/making-quick-selections.html#select_with_the_quick_selection_tool)" they have. By just clicking on the object and moving the mouse a little I was able to select an object inside the image very quickly. I was wondering how they have achieved that ? (Doesn't look like artificial neural network. Maybe some edge detection algorithm) I have search over net over the possibilities of the algorithms that could have been used and came around [Intelligent Scissors for Image Composition](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=218442) but it have already been implemented in [GIMP](https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-tool-iscissors.html) and this tool is no where close to adobes. Maybe they are using combination of [Interactive Segmentation Algorithms](https://web.archive.org/web/20110827180159/http://kspace.cdvp.dcu.ie/public/interactive-segmentation/doc/pr2009-aam.pdf) and Intelligent scissor.

Maybe someone here could point me to some important thread or research paper pointing to this area.